# Is it possible to colour code ThreadName in logs? (Java - logback)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

Is it possible to change the colour of “ThreadName” so as to differentiate the threads running in your application using logback?

I have used logback.xml for configuring my logger where colour for different segments is set as a constant. Eg: %black(…)

I’m unable to understand if colour can be changed dynamically so that different threads are coloured differently to improve context readability ?

Comment: I think it's possible, but not not sure how you could would handle the fact that thread name is not a finite set. Suppose, if thread name could only be 'abc' or 'def' then you can have two branches, if 'abc' then the use red, if 'def' then use blue. Logback has conditional config, so that's easy enough. But you have an infinite set of possible thread names and (I think) only 15 possible colors.

Comment: Okay, i was not aware about the conditional config for logback. I intended to colour code the different tomcat threads which would be like : http-…-1 http-…-2. I think I could pass a variable around that.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911303/how-can-i-configure-logback-conditionally-based-on-context-name). You should be able to figure out how to adapt it based on thread name. You could use `...endsWith("1")`, `...endsWith("2")` etc. but again, if the number of threads is more than a certain number you'll probably have to fallback to black